# XML or JSON Data to View mapper in Android

Tags: android, xml, json, mapping

I have some sort of simple mobile shopping section inside my app. I get XML or JSON from server and want to put `name/description/price/currency/etc` to corresponding views. I really don't want to parse all XML myself and prefer to use some syntax like `["products.product.price" -> R.id.priceTextView]` to map `xml/json` data to Android views.

I googled a little bit but failed to find a good way to do this. Do anybody know some lib or maybe Android class doing that?

Comment: If you can implement it from the JSON response,
check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480634/unable-to-loop-through-dynamic-json-string-recursively-in-android/21480997#21480997

Comment: Initial was to make it without Java object in between but still works.  Thanks! Any ideas about xml?

Comment: Not used xml with mapping or for an android class doing that, but maybe this can help  & chose the parser for your implementation..  
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/  
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

Comment: Thanks but I know how to parse xml, I just don't want to do it myself :) That generates lots of ugly code.

Comment: :) Yes, i figured you'l know that. I checked up gson and xml and found these two links:  
https://github.com/stanfy/gson-xml  
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-gson/ncWGLyEEU5M  
  
Not to sound obssessed with gson but just as i don't know other ways for mapping that way in/from xml