# JSON to parse earthquake data for android

Tags: android, json, geojson

I am trying to make an app that uses jsonObject to parse earthquake info. like longitude and latitude and magnitude form http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_day.geojson
and display it in a text view.
I dont have much knoweledge in JSON..I have seen some vedio tutorial in YOUTUBE but I am not being able to get what i want...Can some one please provide me with The code to do this.

Comment: refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480634/unable-to-loop-through-dynamic-json-string-recursively-in-android/21480997#21480997

Answer (score 1):

You want a JSON parsing library.  I would suggest you use jackson: http://jackson.codehaus.org/Download

Go to your url (http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_day.geojson), and copy all the json into your clipboard, then paste it into http://jsonlint.com/ and click verify.  This tool will help you see the structure of the json file.

Here is a tutorial using jackson http://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-processing-api-in-java-example-tutorial

Comment: i am very new to these things and i dont understand anything.  :(                     Can u please provide me the code

Comment: It's clear that you don't have the abilities to accomplish this task.  Stack Overflow is not a place where we do your job for you.  You need to research the very basics of android app development: http://www.creativebloq.com/app-design/how-build-app-tutorials-12121473.  You should also study basic java

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gson - https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

```
import java.util.List;

public class Earthquake {
    public String type;
    public Metadata metadata;
    public double[] bbox;
    public List<Feature> features;

    public class Metadata{
        public long generated;
        public String url, title, api;
        public int status, count;
    }

    public class Feature {
        public String type, id;
        public Properties properties;

        public class Properties{
            public int mag, tz, felt, cdi, sig, gap;
            public String place, url, detail, mmi, alert, status, tsunami, net, code, ids, sources, types, nst, magType, type, title;
            public long time, updated;
            public double dmin, rms;
        }

        public class Geometry{
            public String type;
            public double[] coordinates;
        }

    }

}
```

With this class made you can do:

```
String data = getData(); //Get your data as a string
Earthquake e = new Gson().fromJson(data, Earthquake.class);
```

Comment: can u be more specific about the this part:                                    String data = getData();
Earthquake e = new Gson().fromJson(data, Earthquake.class);

Comment: i dint understand the last part

Comment: Gson will deserialize JSON data from a string. Your `data` object will be the json from the website you provided earlier.