# How to parse following json response in android app

Tags: java, android, json

I am working with webservice in an android app. I could not parse the following response in app. it always gives the

> org.json.JSONException: Value
>   [{"METER_READING":"15","UTILITY_PLAN":"1","uname":"vinayak@triffort.com","kwh_usage":"3","meter_reading_date":"02-13-2014","ESID":"abc","METER_ID":"abc100"}]
>   at data of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray.

Below is my code:

```
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
String jsonResultStr = reader.readLine();
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonResultStr);
JSONArray jArray = jObject.optJSONArray("data");
```

I get following response from webservice

> {"data":"[{\"METER_READING\":\"25\",\"UTILITY_PLAN\":\"1\",\"uname\":\"vinayak@triffort.com\",\"kwh_usage\":\"9\",\"meter_reading_date\":\"02-13-2014\",\"ESID\":\"abc\",\"METER_ID\":\"abc100\"}]"}

Comment: which response are you getting?

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480634/unable-to-loop-through-dynamic-json-string-recursively-in-android/21480997#21480997

Comment: {"data":"[{\"METER_READING\":\"25\",\"UTILITY_PLAN\":\"1\",\"uname\":\"vinayak@triffort.com\",\"kwh_usage\":\"9\",\"meter_reading_date\":\"02-13-2014\",\"ESID\":\"abc\",\"METER_ID\":\"abc100\"}]"} from webservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using something like:

```
jsonResultStr = jsonResultStr.replace( "\\", "" ).replaceAll( "\"\\[", "[" ).replaceAll( "\\]\"", "]" );
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonResultStr);
JSONArray jArray = jObject.optJSONArray("data");
```

Comment: it gives the following exception Unrecognized backslash escape sequence in pattern near index 1:

Comment: see updated `jsonResultStr.replaceAll( "\\", "" )` into `jsonResultStr.replace( "\\", "" );`

Comment: Unterminated object at character 13 of {"data":"[{"METER_READING":"66","UTILITY_PLAN":"1","uname":"vinayak@triffort.com","kwh_usage":"11","meter_reading_date":"02-13-2014","ESID":"abc","METER_ID":"abc100"}]"}

Comment: see the updated answer. I tried it with a groovy jsonslurper and it seems to work fine giving me the following output: `{data=[{UTILITY_PLAN=1, METER_READING=25, uname=vinayak@triffort.com, kwh_usage=9, meter_reading_date=02-13-2014, ESID=abc, METER_ID=abc100}]}`

Answer (score 0):

try this simple code:

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(postResponse));
JSONArray ja = o.getJSONArray("data");
```

**EDIT**

Thanks @McDowell for observation

```
new JSONArray(new JSONTokener(jObject.optString("data")));
```

Comment: it gives json array can not be converted to jsonobject

Comment: JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: @Vinayak : you want convert object to array - or extract array from object

Comment: i want to fetch record from {"data":"[{\"METER_READING\":\"25\",\"UTILITY_PLAN\":\"1\",\"uname\":\"vinayak@t‌​riffort.com\",\"kwh_usage\":\"9\",\"meter_reading_date\":\"02-13-2014\",\"ESID\":‌​\"abc\",\"METER_ID\":\"abc100\"}]"}

Answer (score 0):

> I get following response
>
> ```
> {
>   "data":"[{\"METER_READING\":\"25...}]"
> }
> ```

The value of data is not an array; it is a string. That string is valid JSON which you could parse but why the service would do this is unclear.

So this should work:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonResultStr);
String parseMeAgain = jObject.optString("data");
```

Comment: new JSONArray(new JSONTokener(jObject.optString("data"))) - i think this best way.

Comment: under data we get the array

Comment: An array value would start with `[`; the value of the "data" property starts with `"` which means it is a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Your json should be like this

```
{
    "myarray": [
        {
            "METER_READING": "15",
            "UTILITY_PLAN": "1",
            "uname": "vinayak@triffort.com",
            "kwh_usage": "3",
            "meter_reading_date": "02-13-2014",
            "ESID": "abc",
            "METER_ID": "abc100"
        }
    ]
}
```

for network call

```
public String initializeConnection(String url) {
        String result = null;
        JSONObject jObj;


        try {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            if(client==null){Log.i("Clinet **************** ", "Client is null");}
            //post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            HttpResponse res = client.execute(post);
            result = inputStreamToString(res.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            Log.d("Result from server:", result);
            jObj = new JSONObject(result.trim());           
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            Log.e("Json Exception", e1.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e2) {
            Log.e("Client Protocol", e2.toString());
        } catch (IOException e3) {
            Log.e("Io exception", e3.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);

        try {
            while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

to retrive from the json

```
ArrayList<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();
String result = networkCall.initializeConnection(url);

jObj = new JSONObject(result);

JSONArray jArray = jObj.optJSONArray("myarray");
params.add(jArray.optString(1));
params.add(jArray.optString(2));
params.add(jArray.optString(3));
params.add(jArray.optString(4));
params.add(jArray.optString(5));
params.add(jArray.optString(6));
```

now the data is stored in the `params` you can differentiate & store it as you want

Comment: it gives String can not be convert to json array

Comment: change from getString() to optString()

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way :

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result); // Pass your result here..
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
String meterReading = jsonObject.getString("METER_READING");
String plan = jsonObject.getInt("UTILITY_PLAN");
String uname= jsonObject.getString("uname");
String meter_reading_date= jsonObject.getString("meter_reading_date");
String ESID= jsonObject.getString("ESID");
String METER_ID= jsonObject.getString("METER_ID");
```