# Parse JSON Response in Android

Tags: php, android, json, parsing

I am new to android development. I need to parse this code to php database. I can get a response from logcat. I just need to parse this to the website database masterlist. Can someone help me with these please. Thank you so much.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private EditText inputCompanyID;
private EditText inputBranchID;
private EditText inputFName;
private EditText inputLName;
private EditText inputGenderID;
private EditText inputBirthdate;
private EditText inputEmail;
private EditText inputMobile;
private EditText inputItemID;
private EditText inputVoucherID;

private Button btnCreateProduct;    
private ProgressDialog pDialog;


JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//   new MyAsyncTask().execute();


inputCompanyID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputCompanyID);
inputBranchID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputBranchID);
inputLName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputLName);
inputFName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputFName);
inputGenderID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputGenderID);
inputBirthdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputBirthdate);
inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
inputMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputMobile);
inputItemID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputItemID);
inputVoucherID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputVoucherID);


btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddCustomer);
btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(this);
}


// button click event


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // creating new product in background thread
        new PostComment().execute();
    }



    public void sendCustomer() {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oAuth", "test123"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "add-customer"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company_id", inputCompanyID.getText().toString()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("branch_id", inputBranchID.getText().toString()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname", inputLName.getText().toString()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname", inputFName.getText().toString()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender_id", inputGenderID.getText().toString()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("birth_date", inputBirthdate.getText().toString()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", inputEmail.getText().toString()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", inputMobile.getText().toString()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("item_id", inputItemID.getText().toString()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("voucher_id", inputVoucherID.getText().toString()));

        String response =  ISparkLib.getHttpResponse("http://192.168.0.110/teezly/API/1.0/customer.php", params);
         Log.e("PARAMS",""+response);

         return;
        }


class PostComment extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}


                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                try 
                                {  
                                    sendCustomer();
                                    Thread.sleep(0);
                                }catch(Exception e){
                                }

                            }
                        }).start(); 
                        return null;
                    }


                }}
```

Comment: Parse what ? Can you explain what is your question?

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480634/unable-to-loop-through-dynamic-json-string-recursively-in-android/21480997#21480997

Comment: do you wanna parse the response? is it a json string? if you wanna put some values on your website database you have to develop an APi in your server that can receive values

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can adjust in your code:

SendCustomer does not return anything, but your asyncTask returns a String for `doInbackground()`.

Also no need to convert to a string when you `getText()`, it's redundant.

So change `sendCustomer` like this:

```
public String sendCustomer() {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oAuth", "test123"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "add-customer"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company_id", inputCompanyID.getText()));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("branch_id", inputBranchID.getText()));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname", inputLName.getText()));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname", inputFName.getText()));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender_id", inputGenderID.getText()));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("birth_date", inputBirthdate.getText()));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", inputEmail.getText()));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", inputMobile.getText()));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("item_id", inputItemID.getText()));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("voucher_id", inputVoucherID.getText()));

    String url = "http://192.168.0.110/teezly/API/1.0/customer.php";  
    String response = ISparkLib.getHttpResponse(url, params);
    Log.e("PARAMS",""+response);

 return response;
}
```

`AsyncTask` is already a thread no need to use a thread inside of it, thats the whole point.

Change  `doInbackground like this:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    return sendCustomer();
}
```

you can read the result inside of `onPostExecute`

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   // do something with the result
    Log.e("PARAMS","result =" + result);
 }
```

When posting to PHP server it is very easy to read the POST variable

in **customer.php** do this

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST)){
    //to check the data
    var_dump($_POST);
    //get the value assign them to variables
    $oAuth = $_POST['oAuth'];
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    $company_id = $_POST['company_id'];
    $branch_id = $_POST['branch_id'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $gender_id = $_POST['gender_id'];
    $birth_date = $_POST['birth_date'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $item_id = $_POST['item_id'];
    $voucher_id = $_POST['voucher_id'];
 }
 ?>
```

There are other things you could do to improve your code. I hope this is helpful to get you started!