# Extracting data from Json object by http GET

Tags: java, android, json, apache, android-asynctask

I am working on **android app** and I want to know **how to get data from Json object** by **using http GET** the (the http request url is APIary)

It's my first time to use Json and httpRequests so I don't know the syntax needed for this

That's my HttpRequest class I'm using :

```
public abstract class HttpRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private HttpClient httpClient;


private HttpRequestBase request;

private boolean hasError = false;

private String errorMessage = null;

private boolean hasBody = false;


private int statusCode;


public HttpRequest(){
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
}

/**
 * This method is called from the subclasses to pass the request method used to this class
 * @param request , The request class passed from the subclass
 */
void setMethod(HttpRequestBase request){
    this.request = request;
}

/**
 * Adds a header to the current request
 * @param header , header key
 * @param value , header value
 */
public void addHeader(String header,String value){
    this.request.addHeader(header, value);
}

/**
 * @return false if the status code was anything other than 2XX after executing the request , true otherwise
 */
public boolean hasError() {
    return hasError;
}

/**
 * A getter for the error message
 * @return String the error message returned from the request if any
 */
public String getErrorMessage() {
    return errorMessage;
}

/**
 * This is the method responsible for executing the request and handling the response
 * @return String , The response body , null in case of errors
 */
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    if(hasBody){
        this.request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    }
    ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    HttpResponse x = null;
    try{
        x = httpClient.execute(this.request);
        this.statusCode = x.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();            
        return handler.handleResponse(x);
    }catch(ClientProtocolException  e ){
        hasError = true;
        errorMessage = e.getMessage();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A getter method for the status code
 * @return int , the status code of executing the request
 */
public int getStatusCode(){
    return this.statusCode;
}

/**
 * A setter method to set whether the request has a body or not , used between this class and its subclasses
 * @param hasBody boolean
 */
void setHasBody(boolean hasBody){
    this.hasBody = hasBody;
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying data through JSON httpGet Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698431/displaying-data-through-json-httpget-android)

Comment: you can use a library or go about it with writing the code to parse tags, for use of Gson, check:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480634/unable-to-loop-through-dynamic-json-string-recursively-in-android/21480997#21480997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this post can help you :

***[How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)***

Tell me if don't understand !

Comment: It's useful but some I couldn't understand :
What is the header ?  and why do we use http response and entity ?
Thanks

Comment: After receiving and interpreting a request message, a server responds with an HTTP response message.
     Response      = Status-Line
                     *(( general-header
                      | response-header
                      | entity-header ) CRLF)
                     CRLF
                     [ message-body ]

Comment: An entity that can be sent or received with an HTTP message. Entities can be found in some requests and in responses, where they are optional.

Comment: You can find more details here : http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html